# How to persist markers using ADF in TangoARPoseController

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I am trying to persist markers in an augmented reality game. Here is the gist of what I am doing:

I have my users recording and saving an area to an ADF. Then they drop marker’s into the scene and save out their position data in Unity World coordinates to a text file. I then restart the app, load and localize to the ADF and load the markers.

In order to get this working, I've modified the ARPoseController.cs file in the Unity demo package to use the Area Description as it's base frame. In the `_UpdateTransformation` method I've swapped out the frame pairs

```
pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE;
pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
```

for

```
pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION;
pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
```

I've also added some code confirming that I'm successfully localizing to the ADF, but I'm noticing that my markers position in Unity World Space do not position properly relative to real environment.

I can confirm that my markers save and load properly based on START_OF_SERVICE origin so I assume that they are properly serializing and deserializing. What could be causing this? Am I wrong in assuming this should just work by switching the base framepair to Area_Description instead of START_OF_SERVICE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem getting the AR and ADF integrated, I had to modify the TangoPointCloud to check if you're using an AreaDescription in OnTangoDepthAvailable() and adjust the baseFrame target as required.

i.e.:

```
if (m_tangoDeltaPoseController.m_useAreaDescriptionPose)
{
    pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION;
    pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
}
else
{
    pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE;
    pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
}
```

That way, the geometry of the point cloud adjusts itself based on the ADF offset instead of from device start.

After that change, when I'm using the sample code for AR to drop markers, it registers the surface properly so I'm placing the markers in the correct spots and orientation. I'm still encountering some flakiness with the markers not adjusting when relocalized though, have to look into the AreaLearningInGameController for loop closure events.

Hope that helps!